# C - How to pipe to a program that read only from file

Tags: c, pipe, exec

I want to pipe a string to a program that read input only from file, but not from stdin. Using it from bash, i can do something like

```
echo "hi" | program /dev/stdin
```

and I wanted to replicate this behaviour from C code. What I did is this

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
 pid_t pid;
 int rv;

 int to_ext_program_pipe[2];
 int to_my_program_pipe[2];

 if(pipe(to_ext_program_pipe)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Pipe error!\n");
    exit(1);
 }
 if(pipe(to_my_program_pipe)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Pipe error!\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 if( (pid=fork()) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Fork error. Exiting.\n");
    exit(1);
 }

 if(pid) {
    close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
    char string_to_write[] = "this is the string to write";

    write(to_ext_program_pipe[1], string_to_write, strlen(string_to_write) + 1);
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);

    wait(&rv);
    if(rv != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", "phantomjs exit status ", rv);
        exit(1);
    }

    char *string_to_read;
    char ch[1];
    size_t len = 0;
    string_to_read = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(!string_to_read) {

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory");

        exit(1);
    }
    while(read(to_my_program_pipe[0], ch, 1) == 1) {
        string_to_read[len]=ch[0];
        len++;
        string_to_read = realloc(string_to_read, len*sizeof(char));
        if(!string_to_read) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory");
        }
        string_to_read[len] = '\0';
    }
    close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
    printf("Output: %s\n", string_to_read);
    free(string_to_read);
} else {
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);
    close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);

    dup2(to_ext_program_pipe[0],0);
    dup2(to_my_program_pipe[1],1);

    if(execlp("ext_program", "ext_program", "/dev/stdin" , NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"execlp Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
    close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);
}

 return 0; 
}
```

It is not working.

**EDIT**
I don't get the `ext_program` output, that should be saved in `string_to_read`. The program just hangs. I can see that `ext_program` is executed, but I don't get anything

I would like to know if there is an error, or if what I want cannot be done. Also I know that the alternative is to use named pipes.

---

**EDIT 2**: more details

As I still can not get my program working, I post the complete code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

    pid_t pid;
    int rv;
    int to_phantomjs_pipe[2];
    int to_my_program_pipe[2];

    if(pipe(to_phantomjs_pipe)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pipe(to_my_program_pipe)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (pid=fork()) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Fork error. Exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid) {
        close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);
        close(to_phantomjs_pipe[0]);

        char jsToExectue[] = "var page=require(\'webpage\').create();page.onInitialized=function(){page.evaluate(function(){delete window._phantom;delete window.callPhantom;});};page.onResourceRequested=function(requestData,request){if((/http:\\/\\/.+\?\\\\.css/gi).test(requestData[\'url\'])||requestData.headers[\'Content-Type\']==\'text/css\'){request.abort();}};page.settings.loadImage=false;page.settings.userAgent=\'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36\';page.open(\'https://stackoverflow.com\',function(status){if(status!==\'success\'){phantom.exit(1);}else{console.log(page.content);phantom.exit();}});";

        write(to_phantomjs_pipe[1], jsToExectue, strlen(jsToExectue) + 1);
        close(to_phantomjs_pipe[1]);

        int read_chars;
        int BUFF=1024;
        char *str;
        char ch[BUFF];
        size_t len = 0;
        str = malloc(sizeof(char));
        if(!str) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory");
            exit(1);
        }
        str[0] = '\0';

        while( (read_chars = read(to_my_program_pipe[0], ch, BUFF)) > 0)
        {
            len += read_chars;
            str = realloc(str, (len + 1)*sizeof(char));
            if(!str) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory");
            }
            strcat(str, ch);
            str[len] = '\0';
            memset(ch, '\0', BUFF*sizeof(ch[0]));
        }
        close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        free(str);

        wait(&rv);
        if(rv != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", "phantomjs exit status ", rv);
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        dup2(to_phantomjs_pipe[0],0);
        dup2(to_my_program_pipe[1],1);

        close(to_phantomjs_pipe[1]);
        close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
        close(to_phantomjs_pipe[0]);
        close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);

        execlp("phantomjs", "phantomjs", "--ssl-protocol=TLSv1", "/dev/stdin" , (char *)NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to pass to phantomjs a script to execute through pipe and then read the resulting HTML as a string. I modified the code as told, but phantomjs still does not read from stdin.
I tested the script string by creating a dumb program that writes it to a file and then executed phantomjs normally and that works.
I also tryed to execute 
`execlp("phantomjs", "phantomjs", "--ssl-protocol=TLSv1", "path_to_script_file" , (char *)NULL);`
 and that works too, the output HTML is showed.

It does not work when using pipe.

Comment: *It i not working*. Please be more detailed than this. Explain what you executed, what it did, what you expected.

Comment: I do believe you should `reallocate` to `(len+1)*sizeof(char)` instead of `len*sizeof(char)`

Comment: @lurker i just don't get any output. Program hangs and do notingh. With  `ps awxs` I can see that the program is executed

Comment: Is `ext_program` an actual executable file specified in your **PATH** env var? Does this program actually write something in fd 1? Also, according to the documentation, the last parameter in execlp should be cast to `(char *) NULL`.

Comment: @Hawk yes, it is in path

Comment: How does the source code for `ext_program` look like? Does this program actually write something in fd 1 and read from fd 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An Explanation At Last

Some experimentation with [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org) shows that the problem is writing a null byte at the end of the JavaScript program sent to PhantomJS.
This highlights two bugs:

1. The program in the question sends an unnecessary null byte.
2. PhantomJS 2.1.1 (on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3) hangs when an otherwise valid program is followed by a null byte

The code in the question contains:

```
write(to_phantomjs_pipe[1], jsToExectue, strlen(jsToExectue) + 1);
```

The `+ 1` means that the null byte terminating the string is also written to `phantomjs`.  And writing that null byte causes `phantomjs` to hang.  That is tantamount to a bug — it certainly isn't clear why PhantomJS hangs without detecting EOF (there is no more data to come), and without giving an error, etc.

Change that line to:

```
write(to_phantomjs_pipe[1], jsToExectue, strlen(jsToExectue));
```

and the code works as expected — at least with PhantomJS 2.1.1 on a Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3.

#### Initial analysis

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child.

- **Rule of thumb**: If you
  [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
  one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
  original file descriptors returned by
  [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
  as soon as possible.
  In particular, you should close them before using any of the
  [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
  family of functions.

  The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
  [`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
  or
  [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
  with `F_DUPFD`

The child code shown is:

```
} else {
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);
    close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);

    dup2(to_ext_program_pipe[0],0);
    dup2(to_my_program_pipe[1],1);

    if(execlp("ext_program", "ext_program", "/dev/stdin" , NULL) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"execlp Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
    close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);
}
```

The last two `close()` statements are never executed; they need to appear before the `execlp()`.

What you need is:

```
} else {
    dup2(to_ext_program_pipe[0], 0);
    dup2(to_my_program_pipe[1], 1);
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);
    close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
    close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);

    execlp("ext_program", "ext_program", "/dev/stdin" , NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "execlp Error!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

You can resequence it splitting the `close()` calls, but it is probably better to regroup them as shown.

Note that there is no need to test whether `execlp()` failed.  If it returns, it failed.  If it succeeds, it does not return.

---

There could be another problem.  The parent process waits for the child to exit before reading anything from the child.  However, if the child tries to write more data than will fit in the pipe, the process will hang, waiting for some process (which will have to be the parent) to read the pipe.  Since they're both waiting for the other to do something before they will do what the other is waiting for, it is (or, at least, could be) a deadlock.

You should also revise the parent process to do the reading before the waiting.

```
if (pid) {
    close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
    char string_to_write[] = "this is the string to write";

    write(to_ext_program_pipe[1], string_to_write, strlen(string_to_write) + 1);
    close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);

    char *string_to_read;
    char ch[1];
    size_t len = 0;
    string_to_read = malloc(sizeof(char));
    if(!string_to_read) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (read(to_my_program_pipe[0], ch, 1) == 1) {
        string_to_read[len] = ch[0];
        len++;
        string_to_read = realloc(string_to_read, len*sizeof(char));
        if (!string_to_read) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        string_to_read[len] = '\0';
    }
    close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
    printf("Output: %s\n", string_to_read);
    free(string_to_read);

    wait(&rv);
    if (rv != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", "phantomjs exit status ", rv);
        exit(1);
    }
} …
```

I'd also rewrite the code to read in big chunks (1024 bytes or more).  Just don't copy more data than the read returns, that's all.  Repeatedly using `realloc()` to allocate one more byte to the buffer is ultimately excruciatingly slow.  It won't matter much if there's only a few bytes of data; it will matter if there are kilobytes or more data to process.

*Later:* Since the PhantomJS program generates over 90 KiB of data in response to the message it was sent, this was a factor in the problems — or would have been were it not for the hang-on-null-byte bug in PhantomJS.

#### Still having problems 2018-02-03

I extracted the code, as amended, into a program (`pipe89.c`, compiled to `pipe89`).  I got inconsistent crashes when the space allocated changed.  I eventually realized that you're reallocating one byte too little space — it took a lot longer than it should have done (but it would help if Valgrind was available for macOS High Sierra — it isn't yet).

Here's the fixed code with debugging information commented output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int rv;

    int to_ext_program_pipe[2];
    int to_my_program_pipe[2];

    if (pipe(to_ext_program_pipe))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pipe(to_my_program_pipe))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork error. Exiting.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid)
    {
        close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);
        close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
        char string_to_write[] = "this is the string to write";

        write(to_ext_program_pipe[1], string_to_write, sizeof(string_to_write) - 1);
        close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);

        char ch[1];
        size_t len = 0;
        char *string_to_read = malloc(sizeof(char));
        if (string_to_read == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error while allocating memory");
            exit(1);
        }
        string_to_read[len] = '\0';

        while (read(to_my_program_pipe[0], ch, 1) == 1)
        {
            //fprintf(stderr, "%3zu: got %3d [%c]\n", len, ch[0], ch[0]); fflush(stderr);
            string_to_read[len++] = ch[0];
            char *new_space = realloc(string_to_read, len + 1);     // KEY CHANGE is " + 1"
            //if (new_space != string_to_read)
            //    fprintf(stderr, "Move: len %zu old %p vs new %p\n", len, (void *)string_to_read, (void *)new_space);
            if (new_space == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error while allocating %zu bytes memory\n", len);
                exit(1);
            }
            string_to_read = new_space;
            string_to_read[len] = '\0';
        }
        close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
        printf("Output: %zu (%zu) [%s]\n", len, strlen(string_to_read), string_to_read);
        free(string_to_read);

        wait(&rv);
        if (rv != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %d\n", "phantomjs exit status ", rv);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dup2(to_ext_program_pipe[0], 0);
        dup2(to_my_program_pipe[1], 1);
        close(to_ext_program_pipe[0]);
        close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);
        close(to_my_program_pipe[0]);
        close(to_my_program_pipe[1]);

        execlp("ext_program", "ext_program", "/dev/stdin", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "execlp Error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It was tested on a program which wrote 5590 byte out for 27 bytes of input.  That isn't as massive a multiplier as in your program, but it proves a point.

I still think you'd do better not reallocating a single extra byte at a time — the scanning loop should use a buffer of, say, 1 KiB and read up to 1 KiB at a time, and allocate the extra space all at once.  That's a much less intensive workout for the memory allocation system.

#### Problems continuing on 2018-02-05

Taking the code from the Edit 2 and changing only the function definition from `int main() {` to `int main(void) {` (because the compilation options I use don't allow old-style non-prototype function declarations or definitions, and without the `void`, that is not a prototype), the code is
working fine for me.  I created a surrogate `phantomjs` program (from another I already have lying around), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = <<%s>>\n", i, argv[i]);
    for (int i = 0; envp[i] != 0; i++)
        printf("envp[%d] = <<%s>>\n", i, envp[i]);
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "r");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n",
                argv[0], argv[argc-1]);
    return(0);
}
```

This code echoes the argument list, the environment, and then opens the file named as the last argument and copies that to standard output.  (It is highly specialized because of the special treatment for `argv[argc-1]`, but the code before that is occasionally useful for debugging complex shell scripts.)

When I run your program with this '`phantomjs`', I get the output I'd expect:

```
argv[0] = <<phantomjs>>
argv[1] = <<--ssl-protocol=TLSv1>>
argv[2] = <</dev/stdin>>
envp[0] = <<MANPATH=/Users/jleffler/man:/Users/jleffler/share/man:/Users/jleffler/oss/share/man:/Users/jleffler/oss/rcs/man:/usr/local/mysql/man:/opt/gcc/v7.3.0/share/man:/Users/jleffler/perl/v5.24.0/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/gnu/share/man>>
envp[1] = <<IXH=/opt/informix/12.10.FC6/etc/sqlhosts>>
…
envp[49] = <<HISTFILE=/Users/jleffler/.bash.jleffler>>
envp[50] = <<_=./pipe31>>
var page=require('webpage').create();page.onInitialized=function(){page.evaluate(function(){delete window._phantom;delete window.callPhantom;});};page.onResourceRequested=function(requestData,request){if((/http:\/\/.+?\\.css/gi).test(requestData['url'])||requestData.headers['Content-Type']=='text/css'){request.abort();}};page.settings.loadImage=false;page.settings.userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36';page.open('https://stackoverflow.com',function(status){if(status!=='success'){phantom.exit(1);}else{console.log(page.content);phantom.exit();}});
```

At this point, I have to point the finger at `phantomjs` in your environment; it doesn't seem to behave as expected when you do the equivalent of:

```
echo "$JS_PROG" | phantomjs /dev/stdin | cat
```

Certainly, I cannot reproduce your problem any more.

- You should take my surrogate `phantomjs` code and use that instead of the real `phantomjs` and see what you get.

  - If you get output analogous to what I showed, then the problem is with the real `phantomjs`.
  - If you don't get output analogous to what I showed, then maybe there is a problem with your code from the update to the question.

*Later:* Note that because the `printf()` uses `%s` to print the data, it would not notice the extraneous null byte being sent to the child.

Comment: doesn't closing the FDs before executing `ext_program` close the pipe totally?

Comment: @Hawk; no — it closes the original descriptors, but the open file descriptions are now also used by standard input or standard output because of the `dup2()` calls.  After the `dup2()`, there are two open file descriptors that both reference one open file description (fun, isn't it!).  The code needs to close the unused descriptors, but it still has two open descriptors, one for standard input and one for standard output, that refer to the pipes.  Note that the trailing closes were never executed.  On error, the program has already exited.  On success, nothing after `execlp()` was executed.

Comment: sure, now I understand, I was not familiar with `dup()`, should have read man page first :)

Comment: I followed all tour tips, but it is still hanging... There is something else that I can do?

Comment: What data does the program produce when you run `echo "Hi" | program /dev/stdin`?   Is it an avalanche, or just a few bytes?

Comment: @user7630704: The `echo` version includes a newline at the end of `Hi` (so it sends 3 characters to the program).  The C version doesn't include a newline at the end of the string it writes.  Is this a problem?  If so, there's a bug in the the program (it should detect EOF even if there isn't a newline at the end), but you can work around it by including the newline in the string you send.

Comment: No, the problem is not the newline. The output of the program is of about 91000 bytes.

Comment: 91k bytes output means that the program was blocked trying to write waiting for the parent to read, while the parent was blocked waiting for the child to die before it would start reading.  You did have a deadlock.  So, that was a crucial part of the problem.  I'm working on the code — I got a memory abuse crash, and I'm not yet sure why.  Do you need to save the whole string received from the child in memory for subsequent processing, or would it be OK to read 1k at a time, echoing it until there's no more to read?

Comment: @user7630704: see the extra information in the answer.  You're allocating too little space in the `realloc()` call, leading to UB.  I'm pretty sure that unless your program resents being run with standard output going to a pipe (try `echo Hi | program /dev/stdin | cat`; that should produce the same output as you get if you omit `| cat`), this should work OK now, even with 91kB to read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited my first post. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In the [pipe(7) man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) it is written that you should read from pipe ASAP:

> If a process attempts to write to a
>          full pipe (see below), then write(2) blocks until sufficient data has
>          been read from the pipe to allow the write to complete.  Nonblocking
>          I/O is possible by using the fcntl(2) F_SETFL operation to enable the
>          O_NONBLOCK open file status flag.

and

> A pipe has a limited capacity.  If the pipe is full, then a write(2)
>          will block or fail, depending on whether the O_NONBLOCK flag is set
>          (see below).  Different implementations have different limits for the
>          pipe capacity.  Applications should not rely on a particular
>          capacity: an application should be designed so that a reading process
>          consumes data as soon as it is available, so that a writing process
>          does not remain blocked.

In your code you write, wait and only then read

```
write(to_ext_program_pipe[1], string_to_write, strlen(string_to_write) + 1);
close(to_ext_program_pipe[1]);

wait(&rv);
//...
while(read(to_my_program_pipe[0], ch, 1) == 1) {
//...
```

Maybe the pipe is full or `ext_program` is waiting for the data to be read, you should `wait()` only **after** the read.